# React-router passing values in replace statement

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I have a route with an onEnter parameter, which redirect user to the default (first) project when they hit "/project":

```
<Route path="project" onEnter={redirectToDefaultProject}/>
```

And redirectToDefaultProject:

```
const redirectToDefaultProject = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    $.get('/api/projects')
     .then((response) => {
        if (projects.length) {
              replace({
                pathname: '/projects/' + projects[0].id,
                state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname,
                         projects: projects } // I can't get 'projects' in the Project component
              });
              callback();
            } 
     // else ...
     }
}
```

I need the projects in the Project component so I can list them. 
Right now I can't access projects at all, it's just not attached to the component.

[The API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) is kind of vague:
**replace(pathOrLoc)**
Identical to **push** except replaces the current history entry with a new one.

And **push** is like:

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/users/12',
  query: { modal: true },
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
})
```

I assume the component taking care of /users/12/ can get the 'fromDashboard' via this.state or this.props.route.state? Why does it not work for replace?